# error opening file for reading: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#define FILEPATH "file.txt"
#define NUMINTS  (268435455)
#define FILESIZE (NUMINTS * sizeof(int))

int main()
{
    int i=sizeof(int);
    int fd;
    double *map;   //mmapped array of int's
  fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
    perror("Error opening file for reading");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    map = (double*)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    close(fd);
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 100000; i <=100100; ++i) {
    cout<<map[i]<<endl;
    }

    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1) {
    perror("Error un-mmapping the file");

    }
close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error that file size is too large.

Comment: a copy/paste of the exact error message, formatted as code (using `{}` tool at top left of edit box) is much better evidence for diagnosing your problem. Consider updating your question with that info. Good luck.

Comment: Which FS is the file on ?

Comment: file contains integers from 0 to 268435455

Comment: How did you compile it? Do you have a 32 bits or a 64 bits operating system? What is your file system (FS) for the current directory?

Comment: Is this a compile error or a runtime error?  It rather sounds like a compile one, though mapping a nearly 2 GB file might be a bit of a challenge at runtime, too.  What is the maximum range of size_t on your system?

Comment: @user3586271 FS means "filesystem"

Comment: Your question was very confusingly asked. The `Value too large for defined data type` message is not related to your program, but to some *coreutils* command (`ls`, `cp`, `mv`, `rm` etc...) used on `file.txt`, and you should have explained that more.

Comment: I just ran into this problem and the issue was a bad file date, 2090.  Adjusting/touching the date allowed stat to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that your `mmap`-ed file is large enough.

And make sure `FILESIZE` is a `int64_t` number (you need `#include <stdint.h>`):

```
#define FILESIZE ((int64_t)NUMINTS * sizeof(int))
```

Before your `mmap` call and after the successful `open`,  add the following code, using [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html):

```
struct stat st={0};
if (fstat(fd, &st)) { perror("fstat"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
if ((int64_t)st.st_size < FILESIZE) {
  fprintf(stderr, "file %s has size %lld but need %lld bytes\n",
          FILEPATH, (long long) st.st_size, (long long) FILESIZE);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

At last, compile your program with `g++ -Wall -g` and use the `gdb` debugger. Also, [`strace(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) could be useful. And be sure that the file system for the current directory can deal with large files.

You may want or need to define `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` (and/or `_GNU_SOURCE`) e.g. compile with `g++ -Wall -g -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1` ; see [lseek64(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lseek64.3.html) & [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

#### addenda

Googling for

```
Value too large for defined data type
```

gives quite quickly [this coreutils FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type) with a detailed explanation. You probably should install a 64 bits Linux distribution (or at least recompile your coreutils appropriately configured, or use a different file system...)

Comment: thanks for your time but this code is giving error fstat bad file descriptor

Comment: Which means that the `open` failed! Or something strange has overwritten `fd`

Comment: i resolve this issue but now i am getting error file has size 0 but needs 1073741820 bytes

Comment: Which is quite explanatory: your file is empty! You need to run some other program to fill it.

Comment: thanks... for your time but unfortunately same error is occurring  {Error opening file for reading: Value too large for defined data type
}

Answer (score 0):

I had this when I was trying to process a 2,626,351,763 byte file (which is more than fits in a signed 32 bit integer).  The problem went away when I recompiling my program with cc -m64 (I am using the Sun C 5.13 SunOS_sparc 2014/10/20 compiler).

The 64 bit system is happy to deal with big (>2^32 byte) files but if the application is compiled in 32 bit mode, not so much.